# How to use log4j for older JVM

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Please explain me how can i implement log4j in older version of Virtual machine?
Please share any document which explains the same.

Comment: What do you consider an "older version" of JVM? The current build is targeted to 1.4, which is several years past end-of-life (I earlier said 1.3, but just checked the source repo).

Comment: Also "I need to do X, tell me!" is not a good questions. If you're running into any *specific* problems, then ask about *those*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are versions of log4j that will work with Java 1.1 and every version since then: see [this entry](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a1.3) from the log4j FAQ.  Apart from picking the right version (in the Java 1.1 case) nothing special needs to be done to use log4j on an old JVM.

If you have a specific problem, you will need to spell it out.